# Javascript library for first access guide

Tags: javascript, web-applications, libraries

Anyone knows a javascript library to create a first access guide to a web application?

When user login for the first time I want to show a step by step guide, or dialog balloons indicating how to use my web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is [Intro.js](http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/) which is good:
you simply add attributes to your tags like so:

```
<div class="span6" data-step="2" data-intro="Ok, wasn't that fun?" data-position='right'>
<h4>Section One</h4>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis mollis augue a neque cursus ac blandit orci faucibus. Phasellus nec metus purus.</p>

<h4>Section Two</h4>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis mollis augue a neque cursus ac blandit orci faucibus. Phasellus nec metus purus.</p>
<h4>Section Three</h4>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis mollis augue a neque cursus ac blandit orci faucibus. Phasellus nec metus purus.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @Lucas BTW i recommend avoid using something because if the user is interested then he will start poking around otherwise he wont being "attacked"  i think

Comment: Well I think there is 2 types of users... One is that you mentioned. Other one  access and have no idea what to do...  So a tutorial would be helpful.